# Access temporary spark dataframe in spark.read teradata sql query

Tags: apache-spark, teradata

Suppose you have a dataframe `df`, registered as a temporary view in spark.
Is it possible to access the dataframe in a `spark.read` teradata sql command?
I.e.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 5), (2, 6),], ['id', 'val'])
df = createOrReplaceTempView('df')

td_query = """( 
SELECT * FROM EX_SCHEMA.EX_TABLE AS EX_TABLE LEFT JOIN df ON (EX_TABLE.ID = df.ID)
) qry
"""
df_td = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('driver', 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver')\
.option('url', url).option('user', user_td).option('password', password_td)\
.option('dbtable', td_query).load()
```

I know that the left join could easily be done in spark afterwards, this is just an example for the principal issue.

Comment: You would first need to write the dataframe contents to a persistent table in Teradata, in order to have the Teradata database perform the join as part of a `spark.read` load method.

Comment: So I guess there's no possibility to do this without storing the dataframe as a persistent table in Teradata?